# Django Server Wont Relaunch after change

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework, terminal

I've been experimenting with both the django and django rest framework.
My projects all used to be working fine, but the other day I had to hard reset my macbook.
Since then whenever I go open an old project, or even make a new one whenever I make changes in my vscode project folder, my server does not update and relaunch.
Also when I run 'python manage.py migrate' it says there are no migrations to be made, even though I have created new models. The only time python manage.py migrate' had worked was straight after using the 'pip install django'.

(Just an fyi, but I completely remade a project I had done previously (a follow through on youtube), when I had first made the project it worked perfectly, but when remaking it the server does not relaunch after changes nor do migrations work)

Comment: If the development server does not reload after making changes to source files, try pressing `Ctrl + C` and then running the server again.

Comment: Yep tried that, still doesn’t work. Plus make migrations still come up empty

Comment: @Arkash Vijayakumar -In VS Code, the 'Django' function is provided by the "Python" extension. Please make sure this extension is available and please try to use the command "python manage.py runserver" to start Django's development server. Regarding using Django in VS Code, you could refer to this document: [Django Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django)